# Router configuration, subnetting, DMZ

Tags: router, subnet, dmz

I'd like to use a subnet of our public IP addresses in the DMZ like shown in this picture:

[image: DMZ]

**Does my provider have to add a routing entry on the first router for the DMZ-net?** Can I assign the whole 193.168.5.0/24 net to the WAN interface of the second router and forward a subnet of that to the DMZ? I guess the only possiblity was bridging then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provider should add a route indicating that 1-10 (or the actual CIDR block you are using) pointing to your router.  It is possible some routers can use proxy-arp to make this work without the providers assistance.